# Laravel Queue is in processing state even after giving tries count

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to send push notification using Job

The worker is not throwing timeout error when I am running `php artisan queue:work` with `Supervisor` and keep on processing a Single Queue item for multiple times

When I tried `php artisan queue:listen` it threw me an error that it got a timeout after 60 seconds.

```
The process "'/usr/bin/php7.2' 'artisan' queue:work '' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.
```

I can make the handler to process everything within 60 seconds as of now, but I want to fix this.

What am I missing?

> Job is dying, not completing and not failing

I am using `Laravel 5.5`

The command which I am running with Supervisor is `php artisan queue:work`

Tried running `php artisan queue:restart` and restarted Supervisor also!

Supervisor worker log

```
[2020-08-07 13:26:35] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
[2020-08-07 13:28:05] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
[2020-08-07 13:29:36] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
[2020-08-07 13:31:07] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
[2020-08-07 13:32:38] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
[2020-08-07 13:34:08] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
[2020-08-07 13:35:39] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotifications
```

SendNotifications.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Redis;

class SendNotifications implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $payload;

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 60;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($payload)
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $this->handleNotifications($this->payload);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->failed($e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The job failed to process.
     *
     * @param  Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        app('log')->error($exception->getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * Method to compose the mail template
     *
     * @param json $payloadData
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleNotifications($payload)
    {
      ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: Please restart your queue `php artisan queue:restart` and try again.

Comment: Tried that to `php artisan queue:restart` and restarted Supervisor also!

Comment: Your job is dying, is not completing and not failing, so you need to find out why this is happing, you try catch is fairly weird, just remove it and the job will handle the exception itself and see if you get anything else in the log?

Comment: Try changing `public $timeout = 60;` to `public $timeout = 0;`

Comment: I know the reason why it is happening, and you are telling me to remove the try-catch code right?

Comment: @TheAlpha I don't want to do that, as that will run the job till it ends without timing out. I just want to handle the timeout error!

Comment: @mrhn I know the reason why it is happening, the worker is taking more than 60 seconds and I wanted to handle that time-out error, and you are telling me to remove the try-catch code right?

Comment: Jobs will automaticly fail and retry if anything goes wrong, the way to handle timeout error is either make the job faster or increase the timeout. When timeouts happens the job is retried. So you can theoretically end up with 2 of the same jobs running if the timeout is to low. It is a way to recover if the job unexpectedly crashes and does not report about it failing.

Comment: I think the problem is with your `--tries=0` block, by default it is 0, means that job will be running infinitely event it fails - what happens if you replace `0` with `1` ?

Comment: @Ersoy, That happens when I run `php artisan queue:listen` manually

Comment: By default it appends —tries=0 as you shared the error. You can override it by —tries=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mrhn said in comments

"Jobs will automaticly fail and retry if anything goes wrong, the way to handle timeout error is either make the job faster or increase the timeout. When timeouts happens the job is retried. So you can theoretically end up with 2 of the same jobs running if the timeout is to low. It is a way to recover if the job unexpectedly crashes and does not report about it failing."

So I have changed the commend to `php artisan queue:work --memory=256 --timeout=600 --tries=3` which fixed my problem.